# Using tab in a dialog box

Tags: dialog-window

I'm doing a program in mathematica with which I have custom interface where I input some previously measured equivalente resistances and calculate the actual resistance, by solving a 8 nonlinear equations using FindRoot.
So, since GUIkit has been deprecated, I created a dialog box where I ask for the inputs and (still to be coded) solve the equations after clicking "compute".
One thing I wanted to do was being able to use tab to move from one inputfield to another while I entered the resistances values instead of clicking them one by one. Is there anyway I can do this?

```
CreateDialog[

  {Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 1: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[req1], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 2: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[req2], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 3: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[req3], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 4: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[req4], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance A: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[reqa], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance B: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[reqb], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance C: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[reqc], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Row[{TextCell["Equivalent Resistance D: "], 
     InputField[Dynamic[reqd], Number, FieldSize -> {5, 1}]}],
   Button["Compute"]},
  WindowTitle -> "Wheatstone Bridges"
  ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a single cell, the default behavior of <kbd>Tab</kbd> is to move between [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField) objects. This means you want your [`CreateDialog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDialog) call to create a single cell instead of multiple cells. Now:

```
CreateDialog[ {expr1, expr2, ..} ]
```

will create a separate cell for each of the `expri` objects, while:

```
CreateDialog[ Column[{expr1, expr2, ..}] ]
```

will create a single cell with each of the `expri` inside a [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column). So, try:

```
CreateDialog[
    Column[{
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 1: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[req1],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
        }],
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 2: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[req2],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
        }],
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 3: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[req3],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
        }],
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance 4: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[req4],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
            }],
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance A: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[reqa],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
            }],
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance B: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[reqb],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
            }],
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance C: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[reqc],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
            }],
        Row[{
            TextCell["Equivalent Resistance D: "],
            InputField[Dynamic[reqd],Number,FieldSize->{5,1}]
            }],
        Button["Compute"]
    }],
    WindowTitle->"Wheatstone Bridges"
];
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you very much!